# Using a jquery-ui widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, requirejs

I want to use the sortable widget of jquery-ui. I installed jquery-ui with:

```
bower install jquery-ui
```

Im using require.js. I have added a section of jquery-ui/sortable:

```
paths: {
    ...
    'jquery.ui/sortable': 'bower_components/jquery.ui/ui/widgets/sortable'
    ...
```

In my module I import with:

```
define(
[
    'jquery.ui/sortable',
    ...
],
function(
    sortable,
    ...
) {
```

This will give me loads of errors because sortable.js then tries to import its dependencies. The only way I could get it working is to add a path for every dependency of sortable.js:

```
    'jquery.ui/sortable': 'bower_components/jquery.ui/ui/widgets/sortable',
    'jquery.ui/mouse': 'bower_components/jquery.ui/ui/widgets/mouse',
    'jquery.ui/scroll-parent': 'bower_components/jquery.ui/ui/scroll-parent',
    'data': 'bower_components/jquery.ui/ui/data',
    'ie': 'bower_components/jquery.ui/ui/ie',
    'version': 'bower_components/jquery.ui/ui/version',
    'widget': 'bower_components/jquery.ui/ui/widget',
```

This seems like a terribly arduous way of doing this. Also 'data', 'ie', 'version' and 'widget' only work if I don't namespace them.

Is this the correct way to use a jquery-ui widget?

Comment: By the way, when you want to reframe a question that has had no answers yet, please just edit it rather than delete it. I was in the midst of answering your earlier question when it disappeared from under me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the modules you ever refer to are ultimately under `bower_components/jquery.ui/ui/widgets/`, then you could use a `map` instead of having a `paths` that lists each and every module:

```
map: {
  "*": {
    "jquery.ui": "bower_components/jquery.ui/ui/widgets"       
  }
}
```

This should map every request to `jquery.ui/x` to `bower_components/jquery.ui/ui/widgets`. Because a map transforms a module name to another module name, then any module in `bower_components/jquery.ui/ui/widgets` that imports from `..` will get a module from `bower_components/jquery.ui/ui`.

Comment: Just tried this, I get the same error, it looks in the base directory for scroll-parent, data, ie etc

Comment: Actually, didnt do it properly first time, this worked, thank you!